# creating prime number function in R

Tags: r

I edited a function which is :

```
is_prime <- function(n){
ifelse(sum(n %% (1:n)==0) == 2, TRUE, FALSE) 
}
```

and I checked if the code is working with this:

```
for(x in 0:100){                      
  cat(x, "", is_prime(x), "\n")
}
```

but this says 0 is NA. How can I include a statement which gives FALSE for 0 too?

Comment: Three ideas for improvement: (1) You don't need to iterate over `1:n`. If `n` isn't a prime, the smallest factor is `<= n/2`. And `1` doesn't need to be testet, so `2:(as.integer(n/2))` is sufficient. (2) Since you are returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` you don't need `ifelse`: `all(n %% (2:as.integer(n/2)) != 0)`. (3) You could replace the `for`-loop by an `apply` function: `sapply(0:100, is_prime)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `ifelse()` statement to the function like this:

```
is_prime <- function(n){ifelse(n == 0,FALSE,
    ifelse(sum(n %% (1:n)==0) == 2, TRUE, FALSE) )
}
```

Comment: You don't need any ifelse at all, since results are just booleans. Try: `is_prime2 <- function(n) (n!=0)&(sum(n %% (1:n)==0) == 2)`